# how to program python chatbot so it trains itself

Tags: python, chatbot

I am currently doing my first project in python building a chatbot that learns and trains itself from the questions asked. How would I go about doing this?

Here is a sample code I have been using.

```
import random

greetings = ['helo','heyhey','yooyoo', 'hello', 'hi', 'Hi', 'hey!','hey']
random_greeting = random.choice(greetings)

question = ['How are you?','How are you doing?','you good?','hows it going','you alright','you okay']
responses = ['Okay you?', "I'm fine wbu", 'not good rough day...', 'good what about you', 'tired :(, yourself?']
random_response = random.choice(responses)


while True:
    userInput = input(">>> ")
    if userInput in greetings:
        print(random_greeting)
    elif userInput in question:
        print(random_response)
    else:
        print("I did not understand what you said")
```

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for an entire solution. What part of your code doesn't do what you'd expect it to do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Unfortunately, this question will soon be closed, because it doesn't even come close to meeting the guidelines at [help].   If you review those, in particular the instructions about "too broad", you'll be better placed to ask a better question next time.

Answer (score 3):

A simple algorithm is, when it doesn't have a database "answer" for a question, it can echo the question back to the user, and then add the user's answer to the database.

Comment: I was also thinking of doing something similar to that but I am looking to make the bot more active therefore using words to figure a question out instead of relying on the whole question to find response?How would i go about achieving that?.. so far i've made the connection to the database and currently uploading possible questions

Comment: @user3537901 It's well outside beginner territory to make a convincing chatbot. But you can have a look at how http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA works for inspiration.